# Can't Log-in to My User Account (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I have two accounts in my computer (admin and standard user) and now I can't access the standard account.

I was changing the names and passwords for both accounts and then trying to secure my home computer with Windows 7 installed by using this guide:

[CIS - Windows 7](https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/en-us/?route=downloads.multiform)

(pick Microsoft Windows 7 Benchmarks; I am a noob, but IMO think this is a comprehensive yet easy to use guide)

Anyways, after done following this guide (I am pretty much follow everything except one - thing or two, adjusted to my situation), suddenly I lost one of my account. To be precise, can't logged into one of my account.

To better understand the situation:
My laptop = has two accounts, one admin and one standard user. I can't logged into the standard user one. Before, when I start I will have two accounts to choose (admin and standard) but now, there is only one and it only "takes" admin's credential = admin account. I've tried log-off and switch user (from "Start >> Shut Down") but it seems like that I don't have any other account, as in it is rejected standard user credentials, name and password.

Strangely, in control panel it shows that I have 2 accounts, both admin and standard user.

One other thing probably worth noticing, I can only log in to my admin account by using the old name but with the new password (tried to log in to standard user with its old name but no success). For example: the old name "tags" and the new name "badges". I can only use "tags" to log in but in Control Panel it is "badges".

I've tried re-reading the guide but I can't figured out which one of them that cause this.

Here is the list of user account and login related items in the guide I mentioned above:

1.7 User Account Control

- User Account Control: Admin Approval Mode for the Built-in Administrator account
- User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode
- User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for standard users
- User Account Control: Detect application installations and prompt for elevation
- User Account Control: Only elevate UIAccess applications that are installed in secure locations
- User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode
- User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation
- User Account Control: Virtualize file and registry write failures to per-user locations
- User Account Control: Allow UIAccess applications to prompt for elevation without using the secure desktop

1.8 User Rights

- Access this computer from the network
- Act as part of the operating system
- Adjust memory quotas for a process
- Back up files and directories
- Bypass traverse checking
- Change the system time
- Create a pagefile
- Create a token object
- Create global objects
- Create permanent shared objects
- Debug programs
- Deny access to this computer from the network
- Enable computer and user accounts to be trusted for delegation
- Force shutdown from a remote system
- Impersonate a client after authentication
- Increase scheduling priority
- Load and unload device drivers
- Lock pages in memory
- Manage auditing and security log
- Modify firmware environment values
- Modify an object label
- Perform volume maintenance tasks
- Profile single process
- Profile system performance
- Remove computer from docking station
- Replace a process level token
- Shut down the system
- Allow log on locally
- Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services
- Create symbolic links
- Deny log on locally
- Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services
- Generate security audits
- Increase a process working set
- Log on as a batch job
- Log on as a service
- Restore files and directories
- Take ownership of files or other objects
- Access Credential Manager as a trusted caller

Sorry for the long list, I am sure most of them are unrelated and there are more that may be more related to this issue (it's a long list). But as I said, I am a noob so you guys may see what I've failed to see. If you are familiar with gpedit.msc then I am sure you will recognize the list items.

I think this is more of the name - changing issue though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, somehow you have managed to bork that user account, I would suggest just eliminating it after salvaging any user files
you need (your administrative account can do that). I would also suggest refraining from messing with stuff on your computer
just on the say-so of some web page, unless you have educated yourself fully on what you are doing. You can then create a new
standard user account and transfer the saved files into that user profile.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer :) I've been thinking about that, create a new account and migrating everything it. Well, it is not just "some web page".. if I got all stories correctly it was created collectively by network security experts and it is made standard by NSA / US Gov. It is also self explanatory (also Windows explains what are the setting means) hence I it is more of account-creation problem because it doesn't mention "hiding standard account" (and that would beat the purpose of UAC at the first place). Won't risk giving lack of information though, so I put it in my post.